# Testing functions in spring boot which have autowired dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, testing, mockito, junit5

Here is a minimal version of code that I want to test:

```
@Service
public class Ver {
@Autowired
private DHClient dhclient;
@Autowired
private DHUrlService dhUrlService;

public String getLVersion(String LRversion)
{
String vers=dhclient.get(dhUrlService.getUrl());
return getVersion(vers, LRversion);
}

}
```

Now the problem with testing this is that. **dhclient** is **autowired** inside the Ver class.
The **get** function makes an HTTP Get request and fetches a response.

I want the test case to actually make the **dhclient.get call** and return the result.
Any ideas on how to go about testing this?
`How do I test that getLVer(String lrVersion)  returns null when "test" is passed as the argument?`

---

```
@Service
public class DHClient {
@Value("${clientId}")
private String clientId;
private HttpClient httpClient;

public String get(String URL){
HttpRequest request//  build the HTTP request
HttpResponse<String> response = httpCient.send(request,HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
return response.body()
}
}
```

the above is the code of the DHClient. Since I want to make an actual GET call using the get function. Probably mocking the object is not a good idea. The alternative would be to create an actual object. But this has fields like clientId and httpClient which are initialized by Spring. I am not sure how to create an actual object for this.

Comment: `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` ?

Comment: @Alexis Thanks. Could you help me identify which fields will have Mock and which ones have InjectMocks? Also do I need to create a constructor inside the Ver class so that InjectMock will work for the VerTest class?

Comment: Use `@Mock` for any dependencies that have methods that you want to be able to setup the response on, and use `@InjectMocks` for the class you are testing. So I believe dhclient and dhUrlService would be mocks, and you want to inject those mocks into Ver.

Comment: @larjae But if I mock the dhclient will it make an actual HTTP call? Because that's what I want

Comment: @larjae I have added some extra code in the question for more inputs. It seems mocking the DHClient won't help and creating an actual instance is also a trouble.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it don't want a mock. I wonder if you code is written in the best way for unit testing. It seems like maybe "test" is an important argument for the dhclient and the logic would be better tested in a test for that class.